# Delphi DrawGrid.Canvas.TextRect changes & to _

Tags: delphi, tcanvas

I have a `TDrawGrid` where I am using its `OnDrawCell` event, and in there the `Canvas.TextRect()` method is used to fill out the cells with strings. One of the strings contains an `&`, but it gets displayed as an underscore `_`.

I don't see anything wrong, there is nothing fancy with this grid, and elsewhere it seems to work fine. Also the debugger confirms that the string is correct when passing it to `Canvas.TextRect()`.

What am I missing?

Delphi 11, 64-bit, Windows 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected. In Microsoft Windows, menu items, buttons, and control labels use an underscore to indicate the corresponding keyboard shortcut, and this underlined character is indicated using a prefix ampersand in code.

For instance, the `&File` menu item (displayed as `File` with `F` underlined) can be accessed by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. A `&Save` button (displayed as `Save` with `S` underlined) may be invoked by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (or only <kbd>S</kbd> if the currently focused control doesn't accept character input). You can set focus to a text field with label `&Name:` (displayed as `Name:` with `N` underlined) by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

This is why a string like `Lost & Found` is displayed as `Lost _Found` in Windows.

If you don't want ampersands to be treated as accelerator character indicators, simply use the `tfNoPrefix` flag:

```
Canvas.TextRect(R, S, [tfNoPrefix])
```

This VCL flag corresponds to the Win32 API [`DT_NOPREFIX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext)  flag:

> Turns off processing of prefix characters. Normally, `DrawText` interprets the mnemonic-prefix character & as a directive to underscore the character that follows, and the mnemonic-prefix characters && as a directive to print a single &. By specifying `DT_NOPREFIX`, this processing is turned off.